# How to interpret "up to at least"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, american-english

So I'm reading a set of formal project specifications written by an American.

Among the specifications of the cool device that I'll be making I have a requirement that says that my device needs to support really cool features.
This is then followed by another requirement saying that it needs to support "up to at least" XX really cool features.

Now, my interpretation of that is that up to part defines a maximum value and the at least part defines the minimum value.
Therefore, I'd interpret the entire requirement as wanting exactly XX cool features, not XX-1 or XX+1.
On the other hand, we've already used term "exactly XX" to mean that we really want XX and not XX+1, XX-1 and definitely not XX+2.

So how would I normally interpret this? I know that in this particular case, I can always ask the guy, but I'm not sure if there's a standard interpretation for this phrase or not.

Comment: "Up to at least" is a vacuous marketing expression.

Answer (score 1):

The "up to" portion of the requirements means that everything from that point down/below/behind (as in the past i believe for this statement) must be included. This is the quantity part of the requirement. 
The "at least" portion of that statement refers to the minimum starting point and is the quality part of the requirement.

Comment: But how is then the "up to at least" different from "at least"? If I say that I need at least $5 to buy something, that means that I can't buy it with $4.99.

Comment: By the way, my viewpoint might be contaminated by extra context. In my case, I already have a sentence defining that I need to be capable of having something. Then comes the sentence where it says that I need to have "up to at least" XX somethings.

Comment: i agree, it is quite confusing. The "up to at least" indicates that you are referring to not a specific value like $5, but something that builds from that which is below perhaps like software. A computer that supports at least windows 8 supports windows 8 and possibly others- quality.  A computer that supports up to window 8 supports specifically windows 8 and all the previous windows programs-quantity.

Answer (score 1):

This could have been written by someone who is used to talking about numerical ranges.  It makes perfect sense to me to see a requirement like:

> The device must operate at frequencies *up to at least* 10 GHz.

This would mean that the device should operate at a range of frequencies, and the upper limit of that frequency range should be 10 GHz or higher (the lower limit is probably defined somewhere else in the requirements, perhaps with a "down to at least" limit).

So while the specification of "up to at least 25 cool features" does *not* sound like a natural usage to me, I'd interpret it the same way as "up to at least 10 GHz."  That is, implementing 27 cool features would still satisfy the "up to at least 25" specification, just as a device that operates at 11 GHz would satisfy the "up to at least 10 GHz" specification.

Answer (score 1):

Was this written by a native English writer? I ask because while there is no specific error, the wording is a bit clunky.

*up to* is unnecessary because "at least" covers the same concept.

> It needs to support **at least** XX really cool features.

is fine. For the first part,

> Among the specifications of the cool device that I'll be making **is** a requirement that <del>says that</del> my device needs to support really cool features.

would be a more natural wording. I wouldn't use "says that" in a formal context.